# Joan Zapata's PDFview for android

Tags: android, image, pdf, render

I'm working with PDFViewer to view a pdf within my app and I loaded a test pdf that displays rather poorly with text edges being blotchy and straight lines having breaks.

If you zoom in it clears(obviously) because it stretches a small area over the same size screen.

If you pinch out to the minimum from a zoomed in image and hold it there, the image is as you would expect it to be.  When you release your fingers it seems to perform a final render and this is when the problems come in.

I'm busy going through the draw method and cache manager to perhaps render a better image.  Does anyone perhaps have a better solution?